# How to display Asset Metadata on a Page?

Tags: aem

I'm learning by myself to use AEM, I'm using metadata for building my own forms for assets.

I need to extract the assets' metadata, and print them on my page, I'm new in AEM and i don't know how to do it. I'm thinking about create a component by I don't know what i sholud write inside

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @Edoardo. Can you please provide more information. It is not 100% clear to me what you are asking. What have you tried so far? Usually, if it is unclear what you are asking the question will be closed by a moderator.

Comment: I need to extract the assets' metadata, and print them on my page, I'm new in AEM and i don't know how to do it. I'm thinking about create a component by  I don't know what i sholud write inside

Comment: Please add this information to your question by editing it.

Comment: What have you tried? The metadata info are properties and you can get them as you would do it with any other properties.

Answer (score 0):

I had worked on a similar use case, so I am assuming this can help you.

**Usecase** : An asset is displayed in page and it will have link MetadataInfo. Once I click on the MetadataInfo link, it will re-direct to metadatainfo page which will display all the metadata information of the asset.

**Solution :**

1. Once the link is clicked it redirects to url of the metadatinfo page appended with parameter "assetpath" containing the asseturl.
2. Created a servlet which will get the parameter "path" containig the asseturl as string and convert it to a resource. Will resolve it to resource till the metadata node of the asset.("asseturl"/jcr:content/metadata)
3. By Value map got all the properties of metadata and created hashmap storing all the metadata properties as Key:Value pair
4. Create a Metadatainfo component which is placed in Metadatinfo page. This component dispalys the metadata values as Key:Value by data-sly list.